# Pproblem loading settings from 2.90 to 2.91

Tags: shortcut

After loaded settings, I found many shortcut keys mess up, including my custom shortcuts, and shortcut override from the addon as well.

2.8 to 2.9 was working fine so I think I know how to do this. But this time it just won't work. Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you load the previous settings?

Comment: Yep I know how to do this as I said 2.8 to 2.9 was working as expected but this time to 2.91 it just won't work. So my thought is this might be a bug or other people having this problem as well?

Comment: Works pretty well for me

Comment: Copy the userpref.blend from the previous version into the folder for prefs of the newer one, or export the keyboard configuration as a .py file and import onto the newer version.

Comment: Ok, I try to disable some unnecessary addon and this time it is work.